# No more access to the history views after migrating from Plone 4.3 to 5.1

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I got some problems migrating to Plone 5, and that one is a real blocker.

Whatever the 5.x version I tried to migrate to from our (add-on free) 4.3.18 instance, installing and migrating to Dexterity or not, after migration I cannot use the "*view history*" button in the navigation portlet to display the history view of the object displayed in the main page.

Hovering (and clicking) over the button, my browser (tried with Firefox and Chromium) displays the following link :

.../some/url/?_authenticator=....

instead of :

.../some/url/@@historyview?_authenticator=....

The only way to access the history view is to edit the URL manually, adding the `@@historyview` thingie.

What went wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Tried to reproduce this, but after upgrading from Plone-4.3.9 to 5.1.5 the history-link does not show up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you mean that after the migration the link shows up as it should (with the @@historyview part) or that it does not show up at all?

Comment: It doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Wow. I'll try to reproduce this on a vanilla 4.3 instance as you did.

Comment: Please let us know if you were able to reproduce the problem. If so, could you file a bug in https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues ?

Comment: Ah, the history-link is not missing, but was moved from the document-byline into the edit-panel (clock-symbol).

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/2823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming described bug and leaving the solution here too, because non-logged in users on github cannot see the whole conversation:

Go to `[SITE_URL]/portal_actions/object/history/manage_propertiesForm` and insert `string:${object_url}/@@historyview` in the field "URL (expression)", respectively do that programatically via a profile's actions.xml.